# Validation of method parameters

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a RESTful web service. For implementation using JAX-RS (Jersey).

Have the following method:

```
public void foo (@PathParam ("name") String uuid) {
    ...
}
```

I need to do validation of input parameters. And if data invalid throw WebApplicationException.

I added my custom annotation CheckUuid (extends ):

```
public void foo (@PathParam ("name") @CheckUuid String uuid) {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to do validation using annotations on a stage when the method chosen, but not yet called? For example using PreProcessInterceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, it was decided to use the standard pattern in the method validation. Because in Jersey do not have PreProcessInterceptor.

Answer (score 1):

Java EE6 has some built in validation functionality.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html

I have not used it however, but I saw it brought up during Java One and it looks pretty cool.
I'm not sure at what point this would happen, but I think it might work out for you.